# how to iterate ONLY the first tuple in a list of tuples?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, pycharm, a-star

I don't know if there is a way to find the inside of a tuple of ONLY the first tuple in a list?

```py
list = [(a, b, c, d), (d, e, f, g), (h, i, j, k)]

output:
a
b
c
d
```

This is what my current loop looks like:

```py
for x in list[0]:
```

EDIT: edited full question.

Comment: Your current loop is fine/correct/obvious. You say you don't know, but you clearly do, so what's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input:

```
_list = [('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('d', 'e', 'f', 'g'), ('h', 'i', 'j', 'k')]

for i in _list[0]:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
d
```

**EDIT**:

Maybe you could try the next() function in the standard library. Create an iterator from your list of tuples:

```
iter_list = iter(_list)
```

Then just pass it to the next() function:

```
In: next(iter_list)
Out: ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')

In: next(iter_list)
Out: ('d', 'e', 'f', 'g')

In: next(iter_list)
Out: ('h', 'i', 'j', 'k')
```